# Open application when file is double clicked

Tags: tkinter

I made a program that manages files with a particular extension (.extension), these are different each time and are saved in lots of places My program has been converted into a windows executable I would like to know what I have to add in my program so that I can run it by double clicking on a file with the extension (.extension) As a .docx file opens Word

Comment: It is nothing related to your program.  It is a system configuration.

Comment: But my program must be designed to support opening the file, no ? How do we this configure ?